# add local osrm sever to mapbox gl direction

Tags: mapbox, osrm

I am going to use my local osrm server in order to do routing in a map based on mapbox GL. In *mapbox-gl-directions.js* there is a server part:

```
var initialState = {      
   api: 'https://api.mapbox.com/directions/v5/',
   profile: 'driving-traffic',
   unit: 'imperial',
   proximity: false,
   styles: [],
  controls: {
     inputs: true,
     instructions: true
  },
```

I would like to replace *api* with *'localhost:5000/route/v1/'*
but it is not working.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK. There are two lines that should be modified in *mapbox-gl-directions.js*.

First: change

```
api: 'https://api.mapbox.com/directions/v5/',
```

to

```
api: 'localhost:5000/route/v1/driving/',
```

Second: change

```
request.open('GET', api + 'mapbox/' + profile + '/' + query + '.json?' + options.join('&'), true);
```

to

```
request.open('GET', api + query + '?alternatives=true&steps=true&geometries=polyline&overview=full&annotations=true', true);
```

Comment: Directions version v3.1.3 do it slightly different in concatenating API and query. Now they put 'mapbox/' as part of profile name. You do not need to change anything in request anymore, instead change two lines in initialState: api - replace with 'localhost:5000/route/v1/', and below it profile - replace with 'driving'. Much cleaner that way.